# Javascript Click button works in Chrome, but not in IE

Tags: javascript

[image: Below is the pic from Console.log from IE. If it doesn't help, please let me know what else I can get the log]Please check the Javascript code to see why it works fine in Chrome, but not in IE11.
When I click the button to create a textbox, the textbox is created in Chrome, but not in IE11.

When I click on the button, it creates textboxes vertically. Please also let me know how to create **space** between each textbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 0;
    function addNew() {
        // Get the main Div in which all the other divs will be added
        var mainContainer = document.getElementById('mainContainer');
        //mainContainer.style.left = '500px';
        // Create a new div for holding text and button input elements
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        // Create a new text input
        var newText = document.createElement('input');
        newText.type = "input"; 
        //newText.value = counter;
        newText.name = "choiceEntry";
        newText.style.height = '40px';

        newText.size = "100";
        // Create a new button input
        var newDelButton = document.createElement('input');
        newDelButton.type = "button";
        newDelButton.value = "Delete";

        // Append new text input to the newDiv
        newDiv.appendChild(newText);
        // Append new button input to the newDiv
        newDiv.appendChild(newDelButton);
        // Append newDiv input to the mainContainer div
        mainContainer.appendChild(newDiv);
        counter++;

        // Add a handler to button for deleting the newDiv from the mainContainer
        newDelButton.onclick = function() {
            mainContainer.removeChild(newDiv);
        }
    }
</script>
```

In JSP button:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" class="bigText" value="<%=choice.getChoiceEntry()%>" size="100" name="choiceEntry" />
    <input type="button" value="Add" onClick="addNew()">
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: About space after textbox you could try using _css_ with _after_ and employing it for inputs in div (selecting it by id). Perhaps also _display_ should be set to _inline_ (instead _block_).

Comment: As a debug step I would try a console.log() as the first line inside of addNew()

Comment: Hi MaKR, Thank you very much for checking into this. I have posted a pic of the error from IE console log. After I click on Add button, (which nothing happens on the page) this is what IE console log shows. If you need other format of log, please let me know where to get it. Thanks again.

Comment: I found the reason. After I change the line newText.type = "input";  from A"input" to "text" it started working.